# How do I create a queue of records in django?

Tags: python, django

In general, when I experimented with the capabilities of Django, I had a question how I can add a queue for model records, for example, I have a couple of blocks and I need to display the model that was registered first and on the second block it should be displayed next entry. How can I do this?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

here is an example query_set

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'article/sale.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

    def get_queryset(self):
    return Goods.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
```

In html, I output the entry like this

```html
  {% for good in queryset %}
        <h1 class="price" >{{ good.price2_text }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

this is code of models.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')


description1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image1_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')


description2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image2_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')



def __str__(self):
    return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text


def __str__(self):
    return self.description1_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price1_text


def __str__(self):
    return self.description2_text
```